# Nested scrolling : ListView inside a RecyclerView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-recyclerview

I'm building an android app, and right now it has a main recycler view (populated with items, which are layed out w/ item.xml), and inside every item.xml, there is a listView.

How can I make scrolling work in this listview, because right now the app just listens to the scrolling of the recycler view ?

I've tried the line below, but it doesn't work :

```
 android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```

Thank you so much for you help :) !

Comment: There is a Google I/O video where their developers do not recommend this technique. Besides that, other developers have tried a Listview inside a ScrollView class. It is simpler than RecyclerView, and older.

Comment: I don't understand... What's your solution ?

Comment: I don't have code solution for you since I don't even recommend doing it, as I hinted before. Your post lack code or layout xml, and therefore it does not attract enough attention. And it's hard to suggest any fix.

Comment: @the-original-android You're maybe confusing lack of code/xml with generalisation.
My code, stripped away of any confusing and special stuff, is just :
A listview inside a recyclerview. I want to be able to scroll inside the listview, when I touch it. **It's as simple as that.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved like this :

```
  mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
                if(rv.getChildCount() > 0) {
                    View childView = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    if(rv.getChildPosition(childView) == [listview position]) {
                        int action = e.getAction();
                        switch (action) {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                rv.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        }
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            }
        });
```